# Attached property not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I am using DevExpress control TreeListControl to display data. This control has columns, like datagrid. I want to show values in the center of the cell. For that I'm using CellTemplate:

```
<dxg:TreeListColumn HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center" Header="January">
    <dxg:TreeListColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RowData.Row.January}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dxg:TreeListColumn.CellTemplate>
</dxg:TreeListColumn>
```

But I have a lot of columns, and the only difference is value to display. So I decided to use a style and pass value with attached property. Style:

```
<Style x:Key="TreeListColumnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dxg:TreeListColumn}">
   <Setter Property="HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="CellTemplate">
       <Setter.Value>
           <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding ap:BenDatagridValueProperty.DataGridValue}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
           </DataTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
   </Setter> 
</Style>
```

And here is my AttachedProperty:

```
public static class BenDatagridValueProperty
{
    public static readonly System.Windows.DependencyProperty DataGridValueProperty = System.Windows.DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "DataGridValue",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(BenDatagridValueProperty),
    new System.Windows.FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", System.Windows.FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

    public static string GetDataGridValue(System.Windows.DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(DataGridValueProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDataGridValue(System.Windows.DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DataGridValueProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Remade column now looks like:

```
  <dxg:TreeListColumn Header="January" Style="{StaticResource TreeListColumnStyle}" ap:BenDatagridValueProperty.DataGridValue="15">
```

15 is just a test value. And it does not sets value in datagrid columns to 15 (it does not call method SetDataGridValue(DependencyObject obj, string value). If I will write a default value in AttachedProperty, then I can see default value in cells. 
Not sure where is error.

Comment: Does it work if you replace Text="{TemplateBinding ap:BenDatagridValueProperty.DataGridValue}" with Text="{Binding Path=(ap:BenDatagridValueProperty.DataGridValue), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dxg:TreeListColumn}}}" ?

Comment: @djomlastic No, this does not help

Comment: {TemplateBinding Something} is just a shortcut for {Binding Something, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}. TemplatedParent looks for control to which the template is applied to, but you're not in a ControlTemplate so there is nothing to find.

Comment: @Not sure what you mean. "dxg:TreeListColumn" is a parent and if I will hard code value like {Binding RowData.Row.January}, then it also works

Comment: Your binding is within a DataTemplate (not ControlTemplate). TemplatedParent looks for a control for which the control template is. Now, I don't have DevExpress controls, but I tested what I suggested with ItemsControl and ItemTemplate, and it behaved the way you described in your question. The designer got confused, and was still showing the default value, but when I ran the app, it used the correct value that was set for the attached property. I had to restart VisualStudio to get the Designer to show the correct value.

Comment: "dxg:TreeListColumn" is a parent, but it's not a TemplatedParent. If you were building a ControlTemplate for "dxg:TreeListColumn", and your TextBlock was somewhere within that ControlTemplate, then "dxg:TreeListColumn" would be TemplatedParent - parent element for which the template is.

Comment: @djomlastic I think the problem is somewhere esle. I have problems not with designer, but with runtime. I mean I can see my default values in runtime(lets say I switch "" to "test"). As I understand, the problem is that attached property is not set from dxg:TreeListColumn (ap:BenDatagridValueProperty.DataGridValue="15") .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modify `TreeListColumnStyle`:

```
<Style x:Key="TreeListColumnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dxg:TreeListColumn}">
   <Setter Property="HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
   <Setter Property="CellTemplate">
       <Setter.Value>
           <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock ap:BenDatagridValueProperty.DataGridValue="{TemplateBinding ap:BenDatagridValueProperty.DataGridValue}" Text="{Binding Path=(ap:BenDatagridValueProperty.DataGridValue), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
           </DataTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
   </Setter> 
</Style>
```